# MMS and SMS texts still going undelivered after my Twilio A2P 10DLC campaign was approved

Tags: twilio, sms, mms

Waited the three weeks for Twilio to approve my campaign for texting (to register my 10 digit business number). My campaign got verified and my MMS and SMS texts are still going undelivered and returning the error codes associated with "A2P 10DLC Message from an unregistered number".

I expected all texts to start going through once my campaign was verified, but that has not happened. I've submitted a ticket to their support center but was wondering if anyone had any good tips while I am waiting for their response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your frustration!

Wanted to check real quick and ensure that your 10dlc number that you are using is in your Messaging Service?

Go to Messaging Services (you'll see your campaign Messaging Service) and ensure that the number you are sending from is in the senders portion. If it isn't add it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Craig! Checked out the details associated with the active Messaging Services and it was set to default and to my initially rejected campaign. Deleted the rejected campaign, associated the verified campaign with the correct messaging service (not the default conversation serivce), associated my already-approved phone number, made sure the webhook was exact for the point-of-sale system we use, AND IT LOOKS LIKE IT WORKED! All my test text messages are being delivered! You've helped so much with just that one tip! I'm hoping this helps some other small business owners!